# Difference between two dates and times in minutes [Javascript]

Tags: node.js, datetime

I have two strings which have dates as shown below:

`var a = '2018-05-27T19:12:29.810Z'; 
var b = '2018-05-27T19:13:12.739Z';`

I would like to get the time in minutes between these two dates (dates are `now() functions from a server`.

How can I achieve this?

Thus far I have tried below, however this doesn't work:

```
var dateA = new Date(a);
var dateB = new Date(b);
var x = (b-a);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: You’re setting `dateA` and `dateB` but then you’re using `a` and `b` in the subsequent calculation. What happens if you calculate with `dateA` and `dateB` instead? And have you confirmed that `dateA` and `dateB` are being parsed from `a` and `b` in the way you expect?

Comment: I see my error now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = '2018-05-27T19:12:29.810Z'; 
var b = '2018-05-27T19:13:12.739Z';

var dateA = new Date(a);
var dateB = new Date(b);
var x = (dateB - dateA);

console.log(Math.floor((x / 600) / 60), (x / 600) % 60);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the minutes and seconds also?

Comment: I get a value of `0 11.548333333333332` in your code that result seems off a bit are you sure that is accurate? I was expecting something like 40 seconds or something to that effect not 11

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs's diff()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to calculate the difference between dates in `years`, `months`, `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds`.

```
'use strict';

let moment = require('moment');

let ma = new moment('2018-05-27T19:12:29.810Z');
let mb = new moment('2018-05-27T19:13:12.739Z');

console.log('Difference in hours => ', mb.diff(ma, 'hours'));
console.log('Difference in minutes => ', mb.diff(ma, 'minutes'));
console.log('Difference in seconds => ', mb.diff(ma, 'seconds'));
```